# Can't find the lord I need to talk to in Mount & Blade. Where is he?

Tags: mount-and-blade

I'm stuck. I'm in Curaw and I need to speak to Lord Naldera but he's not in the castle. Where should I find this Lord and in general the Lord?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normal way to find a lord is to go to another lord of his faction and choose the

```
   I need to know the location of someone.
```

conversation option, and then the name of the lord you are looking for.

This will give you a rough idea of where he is.

Note that there can be glitches here sometimes; once, a lord I was after was taken prisoner, and I only found him MUCH later, after I freed him in battle.

Comment: The same faction would be a big city of the same color, right?

Comment: yeah mate, exactly.

or if you like (bare with me, i dont have the game on me right now) you can go to the Info page on your lord, it will then say his faction and if you click on it, it will list all the other lords of his faction.

hope it helps!

Comment: Also a good indicator is the lords of the same faction have the same prefix. Boyar, Jarl, etc.

Comment: Wives can also be asked about this. I find myself asking them more often, as the lords are usually gone out in the field.